# Instantiate child class inside static method of parent using another static method call

Tags: typescript, class, oop, static, instance

**The problem**

I have an abstract class `Model`:

```
abstract class Model{
    static find(id: number) {
        const instance = this.newInstance();
        // ...
        return instance;
    }

    static newInstance() {
        return new this;
    }
}
```

Of course, we get a typescript error saying `Cannot create an instance of an abstract class`. And we can solve this by overriding the `this` of the `newInstance` method:

```
abstract class Model{
    // ...
    static newInstance(this: new() => Model) {
        return new this;
    }
}
```

But then the problem appears in the `find` method: `The 'this' context of type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => Model'.
  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.`

Overriding the `this` of the `find` method like in the `newInstance` method won't work because we will get `Property 'newInstance' does not exist on type 'new () => Model'.`

**My solution**

The only solution I could find was to add the new instance method in the type declaration of `this`:

```
abstract class Model {
    static find(this: {new: () => Model, newInstance: () => Model}, id: number) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

But this is not very practical because there will be many static methods under the `Model` class.

**My question:**

How can I call a static class that instantiates an instance of the child from another static class(Basically solving the errors in the code above)

Comment: You have the right idea, put it in a type alias if you have a lot of methods

Comment: I have 5 static methods so far and there will be more. It's kinda cumbersome to create a type alias just for these methods. There is no way of making it work without it?